# NiFi 1.0.0 - Custom Priority for Queues

Tags: apache-nifi

Is there a way to add a custom Prioritizer for a queue ? Or is there a way to extend the behaviour of a queue ?

If not, would that be added in NiFi in the future ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [`PriorityAttributePrioritizer`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#settings) to order based on arbitrary flowfile attributes. If that is not sufficient, you can provide a class which implements the `FlowFilePrioritizer` interface (existing implementations [here](https://github.com/apache/nifi/tree/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-bundle/nifi-standard-prioritizers/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/prioritizer)).

If there is a specific implementation you're looking for, you can file a Jira to request it at the [Apache NiFi issues](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa) site.